# Scrapy Splash Crawling Javascript Website

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am able to crawl a Javascript-rendered page using the following codes:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class QuotejscrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotejscrawler'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SplashRequest(
             url = 'http://www.horsedeathwatch.com/',
             callback=self.parse,
         )

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.xpath("//tr"):
            item = {
                'horse': quote.xpath('td[@data-th="Horse"]/a/text()').extract(),
                'date': quote.xpath('td[@data-th="Date"]/text()').extract(),
                'cause': quote.xpath('td[@data-th="Cause of Death"]/text()').extract(),
            }
            yield item
```

I would like to crawl multiple pages by clicking the "Next" button on each webpage. I am new to splash. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather, there seem to be 2 (non-python) ways to somewhat script splash:

- passing javascript code through the [`js_source`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#executing-custom-javascript-code-within-page-context) parameter
- passing lua code through the [`lua_source`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripting-tutorial.html) parameter (there are some [examples](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash#examples) showing how to do this using `scrapy-splash`)

That said, I think it would be far simpler (at least in this case) to reverse-engineer the requests the website is making and implement those in your python code, completely avoiding the need for splash.

Comment: Python selenium did the job. Thanks!